# Chat doesn't pass escaped parentheses and brackets literally

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, chat

While testing a [chatbot](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/2626339#2626339) , I noticed that in chat writing

`\(`, `\)`, `\[`, or `\]`

will result in

`(`, `)`, `[`, or `]`

respectively, instead of being passed literally.

This behavior doesn't apply to any other character I tried:

`\{`, `\}`, `\s`, `\'` etc

will all properly result in literal equivalents: `\{`, `\}` etc.

Does this happen on purpose, and if so, why?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It happens on purpose, just like in comments on the main sites, since those characters are special in Markdown.

Comment: The escape-able list for chat (and comments) is limited to just `\`*_()[]`, right?

Comment: Yes, that's the list. It's a bit longer in real markdown (as you're probably aware), although I'm not really sure about the purpose of all of its contents...